# Bourbon Neat - uneven column count

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bourbon, neat

I am trying to build a Metro-like layout, with various column widths (without using anything like Masonry), but same heights, like this:

```
--------------------------
| col(2)        | col(1) |
--------------------------
| col(1)| col(1)| col(1) |
--------------------------
| col(1) | col(2)        |
--------------------------
```

I tried to make use of various functions mentioned in the docs, but I can't get it right. My current code is as follows:

SCSS

```
// Config
$border-box-sizing: true !default;
$visual-grid: true !default;

// Container
.container {
    @include outer-container;
}

article.post {
    @include span-columns(4);
    height: 300px;
    background: #aaa;
}

article.large {
    @include span-columns(8);
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <article class="post large">text</article>
    <article class="post">text</article>
    <article class="post">text</article>
    <article class="post">text</article>
    <article class="post">text</article>
    <article class="post large">text</article>
    <article class="post">text</article>
    <article class="post">text</article>
    <article class="post large">text</article>
</div>
```

Nothing fancy, as you see. What can I do to work this out (other than going back to Bootstrap:))?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `@include omega();` to get the line break.

http://thoughtbot.github.io/neat-docs/latest/#omega

So since you want to have a break after each 12 span-cloumns, you need to add the omega there.

In your given example it could look like this.

Add this `scss`:

```
article.break {   @include omega(); }
```

And change your `html` to:

```
<div class="container">
    <article class="post large">text</article>
    <article class="post break">text</article>
    <article class="post">text</article>
    <article class="post">text</article>
    <article class="post break">text</article>
    <article class="post large">text</article>
    <article class="post break">text</article>
    <article class="post">text</article>
    <article class="post large break">text</article>
</div>
```

Comment: Columns will be quite random, so you never know which one will be the last in the row.

Comment: Yes, I thought so. So you need to find another way to determine the last ones. Either client-side via e.g. JavaScript or server-side vie e.g. PHP..

Comment: Or try other grid-based frameworks ;-) Thanks for your input anyways - now I know that Neat isn't for me.